# Laravel 5.4 updated syntax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi guys got some problem....

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::udpate()
```

here's my update code...

```
DB::table('gpl_team')->where('id', $idteam)->udpate(['team_logo' => $logo, 'team_name' => $name, 'team_country' => $country, 'updated_at' => $updated_at]);
```

Comment: It's `update`, not `udpate`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its **update** & not udpate() spelling mistake

```
DB::table('gpl_team')->where('id', $idteam)->update(['team_logo' => $logo, 'team_name' => $name, 'team_country' => $country, 'updated_at' => $updated_at]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this i think its should be work**

```
  DB::table('gpl_team')->whereId($idteam)->update(['team_logo' => $logo, 'team_name' => $name, 'team_country' => $country, 'updated_at' => $updated_at]);
```